# Trying to make login+restore password+signup in one view Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am learning Yii2 and now i am trying to do a page that provides login, restore password and signup. View renders, but after executing requests page reloads and nothing happens. Controller has a few actions:

```
public function actionLoad(){

    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        return Yii::$app->response->redirect('/day');
    }

    $login_model = new LoginForm();
    $signup_model = new SignUpForm();
    $restore_model = new RestoreForm();

    return $this->render('login', compact(['login_model', 'signup_model', 'restore_model']));
}

public function actionLogin(){
    if ($login_model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if($login_model->validateLogin()){
            Yii::$app->user->login($login_model->validateLogin(), 3600*24*30);
            return $this->refresh();
        }
    }
}

public function actionSignUp(){
    if ($signup_model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $signup_model->validateSignUp()) {
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user, 3600*24*30)) {
                return $this->refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}

public function actionRestore(){
    if ($restore_model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $restore_model->validateRestore();
        return $this->refresh();
    }
}
```

view forms looks like this:

```
        <?php $form_signup = ActiveForm::begin([
                'options' => ['class'=>'form_signup'],
                'fieldConfig' => [
                        'inputOptions'=>['class'=>'form_input'],
                        'template'=>'{input}'
                ]
        ]); ?>
        <input id="form-token" type="hidden" name="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfParam?>"
               value="<?=Yii::$app->request->csrfToken?>"/>
            <?= $form_signup->field($signup_model, 'username')->input('text', ['placeholder' => 'Username']) ?>
            <?= $form_signup->field($signup_model, 'email')->input('email', ['placeholder' => 'Email']) ?>
            <?= $form_signup->field($signup_model, 'password')->input('password', ['placeholder' => 'Password']) ?>
            <?= Html::submitButton('Sign Up', ['class' => 'btn']) ?>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

If i move all from actions to the actionLoad, it all works, but i want an action for each operation. What should i do?
P.S. if you have some advices for "best practices" - i would get it with thanks.

Comment: all of these things are already configured and integrated in yii2, why don't you look into a clean installation of yii and keep it as a guide if you are trying to learn

Comment: i checked it up and find only login form (basic app if it means something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [ActiveForm widget](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform). If you don't specify the [action](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$action-detail) attribute, it will be the same action you that is rendering the current view (action load, I would assume from your code).

So, actionLoad will execute again, and nothing will happen as that action doesn't do anything apart from rendering a view.

Your problem is that you are using one single form for three different actions. You can:

- Have as many forms as actions.
- Have only one form and change the action attribute via javascript depending on what the user selects.

Comment: well, by adding 'action' attribute to each form i get another error (actions can`t get access to form objects). Where should i initialize these form objects?

Comment: btw, there are 3 forms on the view, the following is an example. or you means that i use ony one view for there 3 actions?

Comment: I ment that you should have three forms, one per each action. Regarding to your first message, you didn't show the code. $action is a property of ActiveForm class, so pass it as an array index like this: $form_signup = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'singup/whatever-action-you-use', .... 

See: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activeform#$action-detail

Comment: yes, i did so. now i get this error: https://i.gyazo.com/cb9dc0cb4db275c8ea31bfe32449eff3.png

Comment: That's because $login_model is not defined in the action you are using... You missed the $login_model = new LoginForm;

Comment: finally, i will have 2 same object declarations - in the actionLoad and in the specific action?

Comment: I would suggest you to read more about MCV and Yii2. If you are calling one action, it doesn't matter if you have a variable defined in another action, as first, the other action won't be called, and second, even if it was called, the variable would be local to that method

Comment: yes, i know it, that`s why i cant access to the object from another action. anyway, thanks